# Vuetify creating v-icon dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create v-icon dynamically with javascript. So this is my code:

```
const icon = document.createElement('v-icon');
icon.innerHTML = 'folder_open';
```

However it doesn't work. It only shows a text instead of v-icon.
How can I do it?

Comment: Hello. `v-icon` is probably a directive/component and you cannot use `document.createElement` to spawn an instance of it (it probably looks like an unrecognised tag to the browser). Can you share a little more context on what exactly you are trying to do (and when)? There are probably better vue-like data-driven ways to do this - this appears to be a very jQuery-esque solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-icon` is not a valid html element. The `v-icon` component will be translated into an html valid `i`-tag with an specific class. Vuetify icons utilize Google's Material Icons font library. So to create an pseudo `v-icon` element dynamically you have to create an `i` element and assign `material-icons icon` as classes to it. Finally you add the name of the icon to the inner html as you already did.

Example:

```
const icon = document.createElement('i');
icon.className = "material-icons icon";
icon.innerHTML = "folder_open";
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.appendChild(icon);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqyxbg1k/

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.